# React js, css url path showing of application in production

Tags: reactjs, docker

I have created react app user create-react-app

I build project with using `npm run build` and serve it using Nginx with help of docker

When i am accessing application and inspecting  the application it's showing css path in app/src/node_module also showing the css path of application/src/css_path

what i am doing wrong here , please help.

Thank you!

[image: React]

docker file:

```
FROM node as builder
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /app/

COPY . /app
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.15.8
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```